# Why is nodeos not producing blocks?

Tags: nodeos, error, producers

I have been following this EOSIO guide and cannot seem to get past step 2 of section 1.5.

https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/getting-started/development-environment/start-your-node-setup

I start keosd and nodeos, but when I check if nodeos is producing blocks (step 2.1: $ tail -f nodeos.log), I get this:

```
   nodeos  raw.hpp:286 unpack
Error unpacking field new_producers
   {"field":"new_producers"}
   nodeos  raw.hpp:367 operator()
error unpacking eosio::chain::signed_block
   {"type":"eosio::chain::signed_block"}
   nodeos  raw.hpp:644 unpack
rethrow
   {}
   nodeos  chain_plugin.cpp:1074 plugin_initialize
```

I have been googling and checking forums but I cannot find a solution. Please can someone help!

Comment: Did you run nodeos like `nodeos -e -p eosio`?

Comment: yeah with the plugins from the guide too    nodeos -e -p eosio \
--plugin eosio::producer_plugin \
--plugin eosio::producer_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::http_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_api_plugin \
--filter-on="*" \
--access-control-allow-origin='*' \
--contracts-console \
--http-validate-host=false \
--verbose-http-errors >> nodeos.log 2>&1 &

Comment: Have you tried deleting data directory and launching again? OS information you use and the version of eosio will help to get better answer. I think it would be copy & paste error, but `--filter-on` and `--access-control-allow-origin` may need to be '*' instead of empty string.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please double-check your startup command as yours is modified comparing to the example:

```bash
nodeos -e -p eosio \
--plugin eosio::producer_plugin \
--plugin eosio::producer_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::http_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_api_plugin \
--filter-on="" \
--access-control-allow-origin='' \
--contracts-console \
--http-validate-host=false \
--verbose-http-errors >> nodeos.log 2>&1 &
```